# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables windows

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

Hi I'm trying to build libjpeg using mingw. I write the command:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-O2' CXXFLAGS='-O2' --prefix=/mingw
```

and get the following error:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

In the config.log file, I met the following error:

```
configure:3890: gcc -version >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-version'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

How can this be fixed?

mingw call:

```
kiril@DESKTOP-4AK09RL /c/Lib_C/libjpeg
$ ./configure CFLAGS='-O2' CXXFLAGS='-O2' --prefix=/mingw
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/c/Lib_C/libjpeg':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libjpeg configure 9.5.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.71.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure CFLAGS=-O2 CXXFLAGS=-O2 --prefix=/mingw

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-4AK09RL
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.19(0.48/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2
uname -v = 2016-07-13 17:45

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: ./
PATH: /usr/local/bin/
PATH: /mingw/bin/
PATH: /bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin/
PATH: /c/Windows/system32/
PATH: /c/Windows/
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem/
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/dotnet/
PATH: /c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Git/cmd/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/system32/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Go/bin/
PATH: /c/altera/91sp2/quartus/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Calibre2/
PATH: /c/Lib_C/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/
PATH: /mingw/bin/
PATH: /c/Users/kiril/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/
PATH: /c/Users/kiril/.dotnet/tools/
PATH: /d/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.1/bin/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin/
PATH: /c/Users/kiril/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/
PATH: /c/Users/kiril/go/bin/
PATH: /c/TDM-GCC-64/
PATH: /c/mingw-w64-v10.0.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/
PATH: /mingw/bin/
PATH: /c/Bazel/
PATH: /c/Lib_C/
PATH: /c/Program Files/CMake/bin/
PATH: /c/msys64/
PATH: ./


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2459: looking for aux files: ltmain.sh ar-lib compile missing install-sh config.guess config.sub
configure:2472:  trying ././
configure:2501:   ././ltmain.sh found
configure:2501:   ././ar-lib found
configure:2501:   ././compile found
configure:2501:   ././missing found
configure:2483:   ././install-sh found
configure:2501:   ././config.guess found
configure:2501:   ././config.sub found
configure:2631: checking build system type
configure:2646: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2666: checking host system type
configure:2680: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2700: checking target system type
configure:2714: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2760: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2833: result: /bin/install -c
configure:2844: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2899: result: yes
configure:3058: checking for a race-free mkdir -p
configure:3102: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3109: checking for gawk
configure:3130: found /bin/gawk
configure:3141: result: gawk
configure:3152: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3175: result: yes
configure:3205: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3223: result: yes
configure:3375: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3393: result: yes
configure:3409: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3419: result: no
configure:3496: checking for gcc
configure:3517: found /mingw/bin/gcc
configure:3528: result: gcc
configure:3881: checking for C compiler version
configure:3890: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3901: $? = 0
configure:3890: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
configure:3901: $? = 0
configure:3890: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3901: $? = 1
configure:3890: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3901: $? = 1
configure:3890: gcc -version >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-version'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3901: $? = 1
configure:3921: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3943: gcc -O2   conftest.c C:\Lib_C >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\Lib_C: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3947: $? = 1
configure:3987: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.5.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.5.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
| #define VERSION "9.5.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main (void)
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3992: error: in `/c/Lib_C/libjpeg':
configure:3994: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-O2
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value='C:\Lib_C'
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=i686-pc-mingw32
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} '\''/c/Lib_C/libjpeg/missing'\'' aclocal-1.16'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} '\''/c/Lib_C/libjpeg/missing'\'' autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='echo autoheader ignored'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} '\''/c/Lib_C/libjpeg/missing'\'' automake-1.16'
AWK='gawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-O2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CSCOPE='cscope'
CTAGS='ctags'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ETAGS='etags'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_FALSE=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
JPEG_LIB_VERSION=''
JPEG_LIB_VERSION_MAJOR=''
JPEG_LIB_VERSION_MINOR=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS='C:\Lib_C'
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} '\''/c/Lib_C/libjpeg/missing'\'' makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MEMORYMGR=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='libjpeg'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='libjpeg'
PACKAGE_STRING='libjpeg 9.5.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libjpeg'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='9.5.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
VERSION='9.5.0'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-mingw32'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /c/Lib_C/libjpeg/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mingw'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i686-pc-mingw32'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='i686'
target_os='mingw32'
target_vendor='pc'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "libjpeg"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libjpeg"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "9.5.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "libjpeg 9.5.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "libjpeg"
#define VERSION "9.5.0"

configure: exit 77
```

I tried to install gcc but it didn't help.

Comment: You're using GCC 6, which is very old. Try a newer MinGW-w64 version, like the one from MSYS2 or https://winlibs.com/

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by installing everything via vcpkg. Thank you all.

https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html